# Laravel eloquent without() in nested relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to exclude a few relations from my API call.

Right now I'm returning the records as following:

```
return response()->json(Ticket::where('status_id', '!=', 5)->get());
```

In the ticket model I have a belongsTo relation with customer.
In the customer model I have a hasOne relation with Address.

Now, I have included the address in the customer model, and the customer in the ticket model usin $with.

I want to get the customer with the ticket, but not the address. I tried using the `without` function as followed: `Ticket::where('status_id', '!=', 5)->without(['customer.address'])->get()`.

This is not working, however the following does work: `Ticket::where('status_id', '!=', 5)->without(['customer'])->get()` I do get the ticket without any relations.

I assumed the first function would work, considering this also works in the with() function, but it does not.

Comment: What do your models look like? Relationships aren't automatically appended to a model so you must be doing it in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

It should work provided there's no typo in the relation name (like address instead of addresses).

Another approach - try the following

```php
return response()->json(
    Ticket::with('customer', fn($query) => $query->without('address'))
        ->where('status_id', '<>' 5)
        ->get()
);
```

I think even this should work (without typos in relation name)

```php
return response()->json(Ticket::without('customer.address')->where('status_id', '<>' 5)->get());
```

This should remove/unset `address` relationship from `customer`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the relation address while keeping the address relation in the `$with` attribute of the customer class, use this:

```
Ticket::where('status_id', '!=', 5)->with(['customer' => function($customer){
    $cutomer->without(['address']);
}])->get()
```

But I suggest you remove the address from the `$with` attribute or you will end up with more `without(['address'])` than `with('address')` if you remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Laravel v10.47.0 (PHP v8.2.4). But I have `->without(['merchant.user', 'merchant.partner'])` method did not work.

This method worked for me, maybe it will work for you too.

```php
$model->with([
     'member',
     'merchant' => fn($query) => $query->without(['partner', 'user', 'credit_plan']),
     'seller'   => fn($query) => $query->without(['merchant', 'user', 'pos']),
 ]);
```